# basic css positioning question with margins and ul

Tags: css, positioning

This is a very basic question. I'm so confused as to why my button saveBtn is not center aligned and it is for some reason floating on top of my ul. any help would be appreciated. I'm just trying to understand css positioning more because to me if I set a margin-top of 20px it should be 20px under the previous div?

http://jsfiddle.net/dasaki/3PujE/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete the position:absolute under #infoBox and #saveBtn, that will make the savbutton in the right place, not floating on top of the ul section

Answer (score 0):

as Zhang Yu said..

**here is it with the changes**

http://jsfiddle.net/3PujE/3/

looks like you should mess around with basic css positioning 
so you can understand it better